# jQuery, display loading page div only if the page takes more than 2 seconds to load

Tags: jquery, wait, loader

This is my first question, so hopefully I will give enough details. I have the following code in 4 pages on a website:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#page_loading').slideDown(500);
});

jQuery(window).load(function () {
  setTimeout(function() {$('#page_loading').slideUp(500);}, 1500);
});
```

What I am I trying to achieve: When browsing thorough the 4 pages, have the #page_loading div slide down only if the page takes more than 2 seconds to load. If the pages takes less than 2 seconds to load (was visited before and most of the images are cached) then the loading div won't show up.

At this point, even if the page takes less than one second to load that loading div still appears and disappears, and it's pretty annoying.

Thank you, Cristian.

Comment: use `setTimeout` to delay the slideDown by two seconds; after the two seconds check if you still should slideDown.

Comment: that will call after 1500 milliseconds

Comment: Well, that is actually the question, how do I check if the page has fully loaded after 2 seconds, and if it has loaded, do nothing. If it didn't load, slide down the loading div, which should wait for the page to load and then slide back up from view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this do the trick?

```
var showTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#page_loading').slideDown(500);
}, 2000);

jQuery(window).load(function () {
    clearTimeout(showTimeout);
    $('#page_loading').slideUp(500);
});
```